# Are there any open-source C64 DOS wedges and fast loaders?

Tags: commodore-64, floppy-disk, game-cartridge

The ever-so-popular [EPYX Fast Load cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epyx_Fast_Load) for the
Commodore 64 included a [DOS wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Wedge) (adding commands such as
`$` to list the files on a disk, `/filename` to load a file and `@` to
show the disk error status) and a [fast loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_loader) that sped up
certain disk operations, such as loading files from the disk. There
were [many other](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Comparison_of_fast_loaders) cartridges, KERNAL ROM replacements, etc.
with similar functionality.

Are there any freely usable and modifiable open source projects that
offer either or both of these functionalities? I'm interested in both
pure software solutions (presumably loaded from disk) and solutions
that involve hardware so a cartridge could be used. (The Epyx Fast
Load had not only the software in ROM, but also [special
support](https://rr.pokefinder.org/wiki/Epyx_FastLoad) in the cartridge to allow it to "disappear" after
a short time, restoring RAM to the $8000-$9FFF address range so that
programs could use it.)

This is intended for use on real hardware as well as emulators, and
ideally the software should work with an [SD2IEC](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/SD2IEC) as well. Also,
cross-build from a Linux platform would be greatly appreciated, though
this is probably something one could add oneself if the standard build
platform were a C64 or something else.

Comment: I think that "works with SD2IEC" boxes you in to the Jiffy protocol, since that is the only fast serial protocol built-in to the SD2IEC drive firmware, and the SD2IEC does not support custom code on the drive as is done with the 1541 for other fast-loaders.

Comment: @Brian Does the Epyx Fast Load cartridge use the Jiffy protocol then? Or does it offer only a DOS wedge and its other utilities when used with with the SD2IEC? I have not tested directly (though I will do so when I get access to the equipment), but [The Future Was 8 Bit](https://www.thefuturewas8bit.com/) seems to [recommend using the two together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-8jobgk4C8).

Comment: I was incorrect. Reviewing the SD2IEC source code from GitHub shows that it supports at least one version of Epyx FastLoad cart protocol, as well as a number of other fast loaders besides Jiffy. Of course, any particular SD2IEC __device__ may or may not support that feature, but I'm guessing most do. The code is over 7 years old.

Comment: Note that C64 was popular before the open source mindset came out from the universities so the street credit came from demonstrating superiority, not sharing the knowledge.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Actually, much of the early microcomputer community was also open source (consider all those early non-commerical CP/M programs); it was somewhere around '79 or '80 I noticed a lot of non-commericial developers were no longer releasing source.

Comment: would this resource be of help ? https://www.c64brain.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Commodore_64_Assembler_Workshop1.pdf

Comment: @marcluscher That doesn't answer the question, but is interesting and useful to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the ones I've come across:

- **SDOS V1.1**, a "C64 disk utility and speed loader," which has had development done on it as recently as 2019. According to the readme, it's "Public Domain: open-source and freeware." It's based on earlier programs "VDOS" (1986), "SJLOAD (v0.96)" (2008-2009) and "SDOS (v1.0)" (2016).

  I discovered it on [csdb.dk](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=176967), but the original source seems to be http://istennyila.hu/stuff/sdos.zip.

  I've not yet had time to try it out (perhaps someone else can provide a better answer describing it), but it seems to include fast loaders for both "Jiffy protocol" drives and others, and a simple wedge.
- **[SJLOAD](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/SJLOAD)**: Fast loader only; no wedge. Works only with JiffyDOS-enabled drives (including the SD2IEC). The source `SJLOAD.ASM` is included on the `SJLOAD.D64` image ([download](https://www.c64-wiki.com/images/1/1d/SJLOAD.ZIP)) and also [viewable on the C64 Wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/SJLOAD/SJLOAD.ASM). It's based on VDOS, a disassembly of which is also included in the image as `VDOS.ASM`. Sounds like it's got some bugs ("incomplete," it's described as) and it's no longer under development by the original author.

Answer (score 9):

There's a recent improvement in C64 fast loading technology made by Linus Åkesson. The main idea is to decode GCR inside 1541 thus gaining more transfer speed.

An introductory article into the problems of GCR decoding inside 1541 (with the memory for both code and data of just 2048 bytes) is here: https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/gcr-decoding/index.php. The main idea there is to have wiser tables and faster code that uses heavily many undocumented 6502 instructions.

The complete fastloader, with the sources included, is here https://www.linusakesson.net/software/spindle/v2.php.

Comment: i love that someone did this recently.  stellar.

Comment: (ok, where "recently" = 2013, but still)

Comment: @Joe I think that six years ago qualifies as "recent" for an item released 37 years ago and discontinued 25 years ago. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is an open-source C64 ROM replacement project in development: https://github.com/MEGA65/open-roms. It contains a DOS Wedge, it can also use JiffyDOS and DolphinDOS protocols to communicate with the drive.